# JS date() returning incorrect date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm am trying to format a date in Javascript but the date command is returning the wrong date unless I use `toUTCString()` which returns the correct date, I've tried different ways of giving the date to the `Date()` function and both `get` and `getUTC` functions to get the date. I've also tried on different browsers (Chrome, Safari, FireFox) and what makes in even more confusing is if I do it in Chrome's inspector is works perfectly. And I missing something obvious?

```
var d = new Date(1324141200000);

// return "Sat, 17 Dec 2011 17:00:00 GMT" - Correct!
alert(d.toUTCString());
// returns "6-11-2011" - Wrong! 
alert(d.getUTCDay() +'-'+ d.getUTCMonth() +'-'+ d.getUTCFullYear());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "getUTCDay()" function returns the day of the week.  The months are numbered from zero. Saturday is the sixth day of the week (in JavaScript land at least), and 11 is the 12th month counting from zero.

Thus, all is well.

The day of the month can be retrieved with "d.getUTCDate()".

Comment: Ok so I was missing really obvious, don't code when your tired and have a headache. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
d.getUTCDay() // day of week

d.getUTCMonth()  // zero based index
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `getUTCDay`, you want [`getUTCDate`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.15). And `getUTCMonth` returns 0-11 (0 = January). [Section 15.9.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1) of the specification may help, but the language is heavy-going.

Answer (score 0):

Use
        getFullYear()
function to get the year,
        getMonth()
function to get the month, and
        getDate()
function to get the day.

Comment: Except those won't provide results in UTC time.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure that was what Udo was after.